# priority queue of unique_ptr comparator

Tags: c++, priority-queue

i have a priority queue that stores `shared_ptr<obj>`. in these obj's there is a method that returns a certain value e.g `obj.method1()` would return an `int`. I want to order the queue in ascending order of this value. I tried writing a compare class in the same file but when i add it in as the 3rd parameter it says use of undeclared identifier(I don't have access to the main function that actually runs the code) I also tried using `std::greater<shared_ptr<Searchable>>` as the 3rd parameter, but I'm not sure if that was the write solution. any help would be appreciated.

```
priority_queue<shared_ptr<obj>, vector<shared_ptr<obj>>, std::greater<shared_ptr<obj>> > Q;
```

That is what i have right now but i dont think its working like i wanted it to

Comment: Show relevant code.

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve]

Comment: What code do you want me to show exactly, im having trouble just figuring out how the priority queue should be written when using it as a member variable

Comment: @P.Murray: Show us a small program which is "not working you want to". Also - the line of code you did write obviously doesn't have your comparator...

Comment: it doesn't have a comparator because i wasnt sure how to write one so i tried this method as well, i just wanna know if this way actually stores these pointers in ascending order based on the value obj.method1() returns or if its doing something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

class obj {
public:
    int method1() const { return 123; }
};

using obj_ptr = std::shared_ptr<obj>;

class obj_ptr_comparator {
    int operator()(const obj_ptr& lhs, const obj_ptr& rhs) 
    {
        return lhs.get()->method1() < rhs.get()->method1();
    }    
};

std::priority_queue<obj_ptr, std::vector<obj_ptr>, obj_ptr_comparator> my_queue;
```

To clarify: The item you'll get with a `my_queue.pop()` will be the one with the *highest* value of `method1()` (because we're essentially running `std::less`, the default comparator, on the `method1()` value instead of the shared pointer). See also the cppreference.com [entry on `std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Comment: yes thanks it managed to compile and run, one question though, is this going to store the objects in the queue in ascending or descending order?

Comment: @P.Murray: The way to indicate a solution works is to accept it (click the check-mark below the down-arrow).